# Ray: how to reduce logging verbosity with the CLI?

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, ray

The default logging level of Ray Core, when started with the CLI `ray start` command is "info", which way is too verbose for prolonged use.

So the question is how to switch Ray logger to a less verbose level?

---

*More info*

---

Logging level controls are not documented in the CLI (as seen from `ray start --help`), but the python API (the [`ray.init()` method](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/package-ref.html#ray.init)) has such a parameter (`logging_level`).

I have already established that the logging levels available (at least for the python client) are defined in the [ray_constants.py module](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/_private/ray_constants.py#L210):

```
LOGGER_LEVEL_CHOICES = ["debug", "info", "warning", "error", "critical"] .
```

Note that logging does take place even when Ray was started from the CLI (not only with the python client).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, do you mean the logging level for the C++ backend, or the logging level for Python applications?

For the former, you can use the environment variable `RAY_BACKEND_LOG_LEVEL`, documented [here](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-contribute/debugging.html#id1).

For the latter, you should be able to use the logging configuration passed to `ray.init` to control the logging level per application. Let me know if this doesn't work for you. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/package-ref.html?highlight=ray.init%20api#ray.init) and a code snippet:

```py
ray.init(
  configure_logging=True,
  logging_level=logging.INFO,
)
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is restricted to the CLI. It stems from `ray start` missing the logging level controls (cf. `$ ray --help | grep log` vs. `$ ray start --help | grep log`)

Comment: I think that's probably because it should be specified per application not per cluster. Does it work correctly if you pass the args during `ray.init`?